# Can I locate top of notification always?

Tags: android, push-notification

If you look at the picture, the notification area is divided up and down.

I want the notification I create to be located in the top area. How can I make it?

[image]

I used NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX and NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH.

It didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: your [`NotificationChannel`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels) should have proper (high) priority/importance also, which is set when channel created